# GraphView appendData() only connects points until 2nd datapoint that is being retrieved from firebase ChildEventListener - onChildAdded()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-graphview

So I retrieved the data from Firebase database which is the "height". Whenever I add a height data, its supposed to plot it and connect to the previous height data.

So this is my series.

```
 graph.addSeries(seriesheight);
    seriesheight.setColor(Color.rgb(0,0,255));
    seriesheight.setThickness(6);
    seriesheight.setTitle("Height");
    seriesheight.setDrawDataPoints(true);
    seriesheight.setDataPointsRadius(8);
    seriesheight.setOnDataPointTapListener(new OnDataPointTapListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTap(Series series, DataPointInterface dataPoint) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), dataPoint+ "\n" + date, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

and this is where I append the data

```
lastlastref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String heightu = dataSnapshot.child("height").getValue(String.class);
            date = dataSnapshot.child("time_stamp").getValue(String.class);
            if (heightu != null) {
                height = Double.parseDouble(heightu);
                seriesheight.appendData(new DataPoint(months, height), true, 100);
                lastlastref.keepSynced(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

[this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpRnA.jpg)

It only connects to the 2nd data. How can I connect all datapoints?

Comment: What do you mean through "2nd data"? What is the expected result?

Comment: sorry late reply. It means the 2nd data that I added to the database reference. It's supposed to connect to all datapoints, like what a line chart would. Like in the picture, its only connected to the datapoint that is 80 cm. Other points going up 100 wouldn't connect anymore.